# Keyword not supported : 'host' error when migration ef on POSTGRESQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, .net-core, database-migration

Currently I am doing database migration using MVC6 on .netcore 2.0. here is the link that I am following, to migrate POSTGRESQL  : https://damienbod.com/2016/01/11/asp-net-5-with-postgresql-and-entity-framework-7/

in my appsettings.json:

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DataAccessPostgreSqlProvider": "User ID=ids;Password=****;Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=IDS;Pooling=true;"
  }
}
```

I start migrate using the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add testPG
```

it is successful and no error at all but when I tried to run the following command on command prompt, the error is coming out.

```
dotnet ef database update
```

here is the error what I saw on cmd.

[image]

can somebody pls enlighten me to this?

Edited full stacktrace is here :

```
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'hostaddr'.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.RelationalLoggerExtensions.MigrateUsingConnection(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, IMigrator migrator, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Keyword not supported: 'hostaddr'.
```

Thanks You 
Frog

Comment: Don't understand why it gives that error but you could try using `hostaddr` instead of `host`. `hostaddr` is specific for ip addresses, it won't do a name lookup like `host` does.

Comment: Hi Eelke, thanks for your suggestion. but I got the error "Keyword not supported: "hostaddr".

Comment: I'm starting to think the connection string is passed to the wrong class. Could you put the complete stacktrace that is before the error in your question? Please copy paste the text, don't post a screenshot.

Comment: already edited with stacktrace. thanks you

Comment: based on the error in stacktrace it seems that conn string was taken using [file system-based key repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers) located in `C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys`, and not your appsettings.json file.

Comment: Hi Set, how can i point to appsettings.json file. but when i change "host" instead of "hostaddr" in appsettings.json, the error expressed that "keyword not supported host".

Comment: Hi Dartfrog, did the suggestion from MSDN[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cec67b56-4763-49fe-a13e-b302bbb5cd10/keyword-not-supported-host-error-when-migration-ef-on-postgresql?forum=adodotnetentityframework] work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that the class which implements `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` contains the correct DB definition for PostgreSQL. Pay attention to this line `builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);` here:

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DomainModelPostgreSqlContext>
{
    public DomainModelPostgreSqlContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DomainModelPostgreSqlContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DataAccessPostgreSqlProvider");
        builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        return new DomainModelPostgreSqlContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure that you are not using:

```
SQL Server connection (using (IDbConnection pgcon = new SqlConnection(con)))
```

instead of:

```
PostgresSQL connection( using (IDbConnection pgcon = new NpgsqlConnection(con)))
```

This has happened to me before...

Comment: Unfortunate that Microsoft chose this name over `SqlServerConnection`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue. After searching all over with no luck, I figured it out. The keyword "host" is in your connection string. You should replace this with server.

For example:
Host=127.0.0.1  should be Server=127.0.0.1